# Updating a column in the production DB

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a dev DB (MSSQL) and I've found that one of the columns (column A) could be updated with actual data instead of NULL. But to acquire the data I need another column on the table (Column Email) so I can look up the information I need. The looking up of information will be done manually. What is the most efficient way to accomplish this? Also, How would I go about updating the Prod DB?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update from a join, use this syntax:

```
update a
set a.column1=b.column2 
from table1 a join table2 b on a.columnid=b.columnid
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess a simple series of queries would do your job. Something like that:

Let's say your table is named User and you want to set the values of the column  email_provider according to the column Email. I would use the following sql queries.

```
UPDATE users
SET email_provider = 'GMAIL'
WHERE email LIKE '%gmail%';

UPDATE users
SET email_provider = 'YAHOO'
WHERE email LIKE '%yahoo%';

.....
```

I think that it could do your job...